# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'poster_path' of undefined

Tags: angular, typescript

I updated my code. I think i do something wrong but i don't where.

I try a lot of things but i don't understand.
I have this error but I don't know how to resolve it 
help me, please

```js
import { StorageService } from '../services/storage.service';
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-movies',
  templateUrl: './movies.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./movies.component.css']
})
export class MoviesComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() movie;
  movieDetails = {};
  imgBaseUrl: string;
  posterUrl: string;
  display = false;
  displayButton = 'Display details';

  constructor(
    private storage: StorageService,
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    if (this.movie.poster_path) {
      this.posterUrl = 'http://via.placeholder.com/154x218?text=Not+avaliable';
    } else {
      this.imgBaseUrl = this.storage.getImageBaseUrl()
      this.posterUrl = this.imgBaseUrl + 'w154' + this.movie.poster_path;
    }
  }

  changeButton() {
    this.display = !this.display;
    if (this.display === true) {
      this.displayButton = 'Hide details';
    } else {
      this.displayButton = 'Display details';
    }
  }
}
```

[image: error]

Comment: Well, `this.movie` is undefined. Did you define it as a property? Does it have a default value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work for sure

```
ngOnInit() {
  if (this.movie && this.movie.poster_path) {
    this.imgBaseUrl = this.storage.getImageBaseUrl()
    this.posterUrl = this.imgBaseUrl + 'w154' + this.movie.poster_path; 
  } else {
    this.posterUrl = 'http://via.placeholder.com/154x218?text=Not+avaliable';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`this.movie` is `undefined` when your `ngOnInit()` runs, as the exception is telling you.

You can check for this as such:

```
ngOnInit() {
  if (this.movie && this.movie.poster_path) {
    this.posterUrl = 'http://via.placeholder.com/154x218?text=Not+avaliable';
  } else {
    this.imgBaseUrl = this.storage.getImageBaseUrl()
    this.posterUrl = this.imgBaseUrl + 'w154' + this.movie.poster_path;
  }
}
```

That should trigger your else condition.

Comment: @KirikKhu I've updated the answer to match your update.